# Dynamically created Array always filled with variables

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Why is the logged Array always filled with data? Shouldnt it be an array with only one then two then three arrays in it?

```
var theArray=[];
function insertValues(species,quantity){
    var w = window;
    w[species]= [];
        for(let i =0; i<quantity;i++){
            w[species].push({
                species:species,
                randomValue:Math.random()*10
                })
                // console.log(theArray);
        }

    theArray.push(w[species]);
}

var listOfSpecies =[{animal:"Fish",amount:5},{animal:"Shark",amount:5},{animal:"Algae",amount:5}];

for(let i = 0; i<listOfSpecies.length; i++){
    console.log(theArray);

    insertValues(listOfSpecies[i].animal,listOfSpecies[i].amount);
}
```

Comment: You need to post what exactly it is that's unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Woah! Firstly, don't assign to window! (unexpected things will almost definitely occur).

Also, JavaScript objects (yes an array is an object, `typeof [] === "object" // true`) are passed by reference, not by value.

When you add to `theArray`, a new reference is created. When you go to log it to the console, it shows an empty array *at first*, but it has actually logged a reference to `theArray`, therefore, when you go to inspect the contents, it shows an array filled with values;

Even try the example below, the same thing occurs (albeit much simpler to follow)

```
var arr = [];
for (var idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) {
    console.log(arr);
    arr[idx] = idx;
}
```

to prevent this, you would need to copy the array, like so:

```
var newArray = Object.assign([], theArray);
```

`Object.assign` copies the values of the array (or object), returning a new array (again, or object), but does not create a reference back to the original array or object.